# How to define the default path for python3 in the terminal of VSCode, to point to the active Conda environment

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code

In my MacOS Terminal, I have:

```
which python3
~miniconda3/envs/django/bin/python3
```

but if I open a terminal inside Visual Studio Code I have:

```
which python3
~/homebrew/bin/python3
```

I am using bash in both, but it seems they have different settings in both terminals. Why? How could I force VSCode to search for python3 in the actual activated Conda?

[UPDATE]

I found that  if I run the following, after opening the new terminal in vscode:

```
export PATH="~/miniconda3/bin/:$PATH"
```

Then everything works properly. So it seems that the PATH is different in VSCode integrated terminal and in my MacOS terminal, and I don't know why. And the main problem is that my solution only works while the terminal window is open, I have to run that every time. Any suggestion?

Comment: you need to set the interpreter for your project. then VSCode will automatically activate it if it recognizes it as a conda environment, at least, in my experience it has worked that way. It should be on the bottom right of the editor window. Do you see it? It's probably set to the brew python

Comment: Yes, it should work that way, but it does not in my case. I have the interpreted properly selected. It works right if I use "Run Python file in Terminal". And if I "Open new Terminal", it properly activate the conda environment, but still python3 is associated to the wrong path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Configure environment variables for the terminal with the following setting:

```
    "terminal.integrated.env.osx": {
        "PATH":"${env:PATH}:~/miniconda3/bin/:$PATH"
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! It looks very good. Unfortunatelly I can not checking since my problem is not arising any more. I can not vote you up your answer since I have not enough reputation yet. Anyway, I still do not know the reason why vscode load different settings than my terminal.